# How to use CrossValidator to choose between different models

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cross-validation

I know that I can use a [CrossValidator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator) to tune a single model. But what is the suggested approach for evaluating different models against each other? For example, say that I wanted to evaluate a [LogisticRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression) classifier against a [LinearSVC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LinearSVC) classifier using [CrossValidator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After familiarizing myself a bit with the API, I solved this problem by implementing a custom [Estimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#estimators) that wraps two or more estimators it can delegate to, where the selected estimator is controlled by a single [Param[Int]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param). Here is the actual code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator
import org.apache.spark.ml.Model
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.Param
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

trait DelegatingEstimatorModelParams extends Params {
  final val selectedEstimator = new Param[Int](this, "selectedEstimator", "The selected estimator")
}

class DelegatingEstimator private (override val uid: String, delegates: Array[Estimator[_]]) extends Estimator[DelegatingEstimatorModel] with DelegatingEstimatorModelParams {
  private def this(estimators: Array[Estimator[_]]) = this(Identifiable.randomUID("delegating-estimator"), estimators)

  def this(estimator1: Estimator[_], estimator2: Estimator[_], estimators: Estimator[_]*) = {
    this((Seq(estimator1, estimator2) ++ estimators).toArray)
  }

  setDefault(selectedEstimator -> 0)

  override def fit(dataset: Dataset[_]): DelegatingEstimatorModel = {
    val estimator = delegates(getOrDefault(selectedEstimator))
    val model = estimator.fit(dataset).asInstanceOf[Model[_]]
    new DelegatingEstimatorModel(uid, model)
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Estimator[DelegatingEstimatorModel] = {
    val that = new DelegatingEstimator(uid, delegates)
    copyValues(that, extra)
  }

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    // All delegates are assumed to perform the same schema transformation,
    // so we can simply select the first one:
    delegates(0).transformSchema(schema)
  }
}

class DelegatingEstimatorModel(override val uid: String, val delegate: Model[_]) extends Model[DelegatingEstimatorModel] with DelegatingEstimatorModelParams {
  def copy(extra: ParamMap): DelegatingEstimatorModel = new DelegatingEstimatorModel(uid, delegate.copy(extra).asInstanceOf[Model[_]])

  def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = delegate.transform(dataset)

  def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = delegate.transformSchema(schema)
}
```

The evaluate a [LogistcRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression) against a [LinearSVC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LinearSVC) the classes from above can be employed like this:

```
val logRegression = new LogisticRegression()
  .setFeaturesCol(columnNames.features)
  .setPredictionCol(columnNames.prediction)
  .setRawPredictionCol(columnNames.rawPrediciton)
  .setLabelCol(columnNames.label)

val svmEstimator = new LinearSVC()
  .setFeaturesCol(columnNames.features)
  .setPredictionCol(columnNames.prediction)
  .setRawPredictionCol(columnNames.rawPrediciton)
  .setLabelCol(columnNames.label)

val delegatingEstimator = new DelegatingEstimator(logRegression, svmEstimator)

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
  .addGrid(delegatingEstimator.selectedEstimator, Array(0, 1))
  .build()

val model = crossValidator.fit(data)

val bestModel = model.bestModel.asInstanceOf[DelegatingEstimatorModel].delegate
```